# how do I select an id and a child tag with Jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying to select a ul that has an id attribute. It has li tags and within the li tags there are anchor tags. When I mouse out I want the ul and all the elements in it to be hidden.

```
$('#switch-fighters-results-list').mouseout(function(){
  $(this).hide();
});
```

here is the markup

```
<div style="display: block;" id="switch-fighters-results" class="ajax-search-results">
        <ul id="switch-fighters-results-list" class="ajax-search-results-list clrFx">
            <li onmouseout="removeCurrent(this);" onmouseover="addCurrent(this);" class="">
                <a href="/fighter/scott/ferrozzo/56">Scott Ferrozzo</a>
            </li>
            <li onmouseout="removeCurrent(this);" onmouseover="addCurrent(this);" class="">
                <a href="/fighter/scott/bessac/63">Scott Bessac</a>
            </li>
            <li onmouseout="removeCurrent(this);" onmouseover="addCurrent(this);" class="">
                <a href="/fighter/scott/adams/191">Scott Adams</a>
            </li>
            <li onmouseout="removeCurrent(this);" onmouseover="addCurrent(this);" class="">
                <a href="/fighter/scott/junk/362">Scott Junk</a>
            </li>
            <li onmouseout="removeCurrent(this);" onmouseover="addCurrent(this);" class="">
                <a href="/fighter/scott/smith/376">Scott Smith</a>
            </li>
            <li onmouseout="removeCurrent(this);" onmouseover="addCurrent(this);" class="">
                <a href="/fighter/scott/baker/555">Scott Baker</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div id="switch-fighter-more-results">
            <a id="switch-fighter-more-results-link">13 more found for <span class="input-string">'scott'</span> »</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: can you post your markup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using `hover` instead? I was able to use `hover` where `mouseout` did not work

[Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/Jaybles/vgeY7/)

```
$('#switch-fighters-results-list').hover(function(){},function(){
    $('#switch-fighters-results-list').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#ul[id=id]").find("li").each(function(){
   $(this).mouseout(//do something);
});
```

Comment: This is a hack, as it does not directly address the problem.

Comment: In addition, this is how you select based on attributes, but you should use "#" when selecting by id, as it is standard. For instance, you could rewrite your entire selector to "#myid li", and be done.

Answer (score 0):

From the info given, I would say to add "li" in the selector if "switch-fighters-results-list" is the id of the ul:

```
$('#switch-fighters-results-list li').mouseout(function(){
  $(this).hide();
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think OP wants to remove the entire `ul` when the mouse leaves.

Comment: Correct, this is also a hack, and doesn't get rid of the ul. Try using mouseleave on the ul instead.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it makes a difference but I was thinking that the propper approach would be:

```
$('#switch-fighters-results-list ul').mouseout(function(){  $(this).hide();});
```

Answer (score 0):

> how do I select an id and a child tag
>   with Jquery?

You would use this:

```
$('#switch-fighters-results-list li').mouseleave(function(){
  $(this).hide();
});
```

Where "li" is the child selector. Notice the space :)

However, mouseout is probably not going to do what you expect.

mouseover and mouseout fire every time the mouse cursor hovers over another element, or no longer has a direct "line of sight" to the element for which it fires. mouseenter and mouseleave, on the other hand, fire whenever the mouse leaves the bounding box of the element. Try using mouseleave instead of mouseout.

check this out:

**http://jsfiddle.net/FVPxP/3/**

The easiest way to hide the entire ul is the following:

This solution directly addresses the problem you have, and completed *hides* the UL upon exiting it's bounding box.

```
<ul id="switch-fighters-results-list">
    <li><a href="lego.com">Lego.com</a></li>
    <li><a href="lego.com">Lego.com</a></li>
    <li><a href="lego.com">Lego.com</a></li>
    <li><a href="lego.com">Lego.com</a></li>
    <li><a href="lego.com">Lego.com</a></li>
</ul>

$('#switch-fighters-results-list').mouseleave(function(){
  $(this).hide();
});
```

In addition, you won't have to make all of the child li's visible again upon entering the ul, so this is the most direct approach.